# joomla wrong base href results in wrong CSS template

Tags: css, joomla

I have installed `Joomla` 3.x and some modules.

One of my modules is to display articles from certain categories of my articles, but when I [navigate to my article](http://cambridge.mywebcommunity.org/index.php/10-%E7%88%B1%E7%AB%8B%E6%96%B9%E5%8A%A8%E5%90%91%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0/3-welcome-to-your-blog), the `CSS` stylesheets do not load.

When I view the source, I discovered that the URL for the CSS stylesheet in the page above becomes:

```
<base href="http://cambridge.mywebcommunity.org/index.php/10-%E7%88%B1%E7%AB%8B%E6%96%B9%E5%8A%A8%E5%90%91%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0/3-welcome-to-your-blog" />
```

... instead of the original I put in, here:

```
<base href="http://cambridge.mywebcommunity.org/" />
```

This also happens to another CSS stylesheet from the module. The CSS URL loads like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cambridge.mywebcommunity.org/10-爱立方动向更新/modules/mod_news_pro_gk5/interface/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

... instead of the original CSS URL that I put in:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cambridge.mywebcommunity.org/modules/mod_news_pro_gk5/interface/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

So I have figured out that the issue is the URLs are not being added by Joomla correctly. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: ensure the system-SEF plugin is enabled, if possible also enable .htaccess - based SEF routing (in the global configuration) this usually solves it; if it doesn't proceed with code editing as per @Elin's post.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted it looks like you (or extension developers) are trying to add css with absolute links. Looking at the source of your page will quickly show you that your links look different from the core links in that they are absolute not relative. You may need to look a the code in the modules doing this and fix or contact the developers and ask them to fix. Also ask them about the js.

In Joomla you add style sheets with code like this in your template index:

$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/template.css');

The change in behavior is most likely due to a recent security fix concerning uris in the header. I'm not going to link to details of the exploit but easy enough to find out why this was changed, but it was for good reasons.